# I need a wiring solution for an unusual situation

Tags: electrical

I have two 20amp circuits in the kitchen. One is controlling receptacles to the left of the sink AND the dishwasher.  The other is controlling receptacles to the right of the sink AND the fridge.  The disposer is on it's own 20amp circuit.  Since counter receptacles are used far more frequently than the disposer is and more likely to trip the GFCI killing power to the fridge, would the lesser of two evils be to place the fridge on the same circuit as the disposer and get it off the circuit that controls two receptacles to the right of the sink?

Comment: There's a reason the countertop circuits are not supposed to be shared with anything else.

Comment: Is the garbage disposal cord-and-plug connected to a switched receptacle, or hardwired?

Comment: Also, how much current do your dishwasher and disposal use?

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, although you are swapping one code violation for another. The fridge CAN be on with the small appliance counter circuit, but the DW cannot (which is how you have it now).

If the fridge is kept off the SABC (small appliance branch circuit) then it must be on it's own circuit. At the same time, I do agree that having the fridge on with the disposal is the lesser of two evils as opposed to having it on with the counter circuit and GFI protected.

I still do NOT like that the DW is on with the SABC. The DW is likely more of a draw than the fridge, but you have the option of not using the DW at times when small appliances are being used. The fridge does not allow you this flexibility.

I am not an advocate of code violations, but swapping a minor code violation for an even lesser one IMO is not a bad thing to do.

Best case scenario:

- Combine the DW and disposal on the 20A circuit.
- Give the refer it's own new 15 or 20A circuit.
- Keep the two SABC's dedicated to the counter receptacles.

Answer (score 0):

### There are a few ways out of this pickle, but it depends on precisely how things are wired up, and how much current they draw

#### Pulling Wire

If you can pull a new home run from the panel + add a C/B (i.e. add a brand new circuit), I would recommend what Speedy said:

- Put the dishwasher and garbage disposal on the circuit that is currently feeding the disposal
- Pull a new 15A circuit for the refrigerator and install a dedicated single outlet for it
- Make it so that the two small-appliance branch circuits *only* feed the kitchen countertops, as it appears that the kitchen wall and dining room outlets are on a separate circuit

#### Clever GFCI placement

If you can't do that, can you at least place the GFCI for the countertop receptacles downstream of the fridge on that side's small-appliance branch circuit?  That would alleviate your concerns about GFCI trips killing power to the refrigerator.

Once you do that, then there is a Code-compliant, albeit ugly, way to untangle everything else, using Exception 1 to 210.52(B):

> **(B) Small Appliances.**
>
> **(1) Receptacle Outlets Served.** In the kitchen, pantry,
>   breakfast room, dining room, or similar area of a dwelling
>   unit, the two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch
>   circuits required by 210.11(C)(1) shall serve all wall and
>   floor receptacle outlets covered by 210.52(A), all counter-
>   top outlets covered by 210.52(C), and receptacle outlets for
>   refrigeration equipment.
>
> *Exception No.1: In addition to the required receptacles
>   specified by 210.52, switched receptacles supplied from a
>   general-purpose branch circuit as defined in 210.70(A)(1),
>   Exception No.1, shall be permitted.*

With this, you can:

- Move the garbage disposal to the *general kitchen lighting circuit* provided it doesn't overload the circuit
- Move the dishwasher to the 20A circuit freed up by the garbage disposal moving
- Leave the fridge one one of the small-appliance branch circuits and have the other one free to supply receptacles exclusively

#### My kitchen lighting circuit can't take any more!

If you cannot move the disposal to the kitchen lighting circuit, you can put the disposal and the dishwasher on the same circuit after moving the GFCI -- this would also comply with Code regarding kitchen branch circuits, but may or may not be more desirable than putting the disposal on the lighting circuit, depending on how much current the disposal and dishwasher draw.